# how to show the only the loding.gif on (onclick) with flask backend?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flask

I am new to jquery & js. I am using a flask application for my mini project.

I am calling the loding.gif file via js/jquery script. it is working like when I hit submit button in html loding.gif file is called, but it is showing below to the submit button itself.

I want like 'if I hit submit button in html, only loding.gif as to show' other content like form name dropdown, everything has to hide.

what I need to change?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

  <h1>The select form attribute</h1>
  <right>
    <!--<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l1J9LIsJB4xHMzLLq/giphy.gif">-->
</right>
<div class="zoom"></div>
<form method="POST"  id="carform">
  <label for="uname">Firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
    <br>

    <select id="cars" name="carfs">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <select id="image" name="image">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option value="debian">debian</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
    </select>


<!--<input type="submit" value="Submit">-->

  <input type="submit" name="anything_submit" value="Submit" onclick="$('#loading').show();">
</form>
  <div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='loder.gif')}}" alt="loading......" />Loading...!</div>

<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your form inside a div and hide it when you submit your form. So, there's not much more to be added. Take a look:

```js
 $('#submit_leave_email').submit(function(e) {
    $("#will_hide").hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    setTimeout(()=>{
       $('#loading').replaceWith("<img src='https://c.tenor.com/Kt8pNHXHLKwAAAAC/module-free.gif' width='100'>");
    }, 3000)
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="will_hide">
    <form id='submit_leave_email' method='post'>
      <label for="uname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
      <br>

      <select id="cars" name="carfs">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <select id="image" name="image">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
        <option value="debian">debian</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
      </select>

      <button type='submit' class='input_button' value='submit'>Insert </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="loading" style="display:none">
    <p>Loading...!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice that I used the `setTimeout` just to simulate the delay of backend's response and `e.preventDefault()` to avoid submitting the form from here.

Comment: hi @testing_22, thanks for the help, gif perfectly loading as per your code  but the full gif i can't see its out of fit screen... so in order to make fit to screen pls suggest were to edit or pls share the re-edited code to fit the gif with the scree........ **(its like, i need to scroll up/down to see full gif while loading )**

Comment: Hi @sudhar chrome. You can change the value of the width attribute in the `img` tag in order to make it fit. `<img src='your_src' width='your_width'>`